# Dynamic template in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, templates

**Background**

I have a gamification project going with my poker stuying and I would like to create an Excel file that is similar to old text-based games. I want a menu and a character panel (showing progression) to follow me on every sheet within that Excel file. I think that what I want is a dynamic template(?) but I am open to other suggestions as I have no previous experience with Excel at all.

**Questions**

- Is it possible to have a template that is similar in every work sheet, but also have unique information? In the picture below I want 1 (the menu), 2 (the header), 3 (the character panel) and 4 (the empty box of start date) to be the template that every work sheet has. 1,2, and 3 will look similar in all work sheets, but 4 will have a text and pictures that is unique to that work sheet.
- Is it also possible to update this template later so that it automatically updates the template in all the other work sheets? I might want to make the menu smaller or bigger, add more pictures and information in the character panel/progression part later. When updating the template will it erase all the unique information in 4?

Is it clear what I want to achieve?
[My current excel workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z7JL.png)

Comment: What you described is not the functionality of templates. You might achieve what you need with formulas / macro

Comment: Do you know what the formulas / macros would look like - or what I would have to search for on Google to figure it out?

Comment: Your requirement is not very clearly.

Comment: A general question such as this will only result in general responses. If you want your template to be your output, then yes, you can do that in excel (but is it the best choice). You didn't specify where data is coming from (input). Once these are identified, processes can be determined (whether functions/formulas or VBA).

Comment: `Is it also possible to update this template later`  >> post the template link on shared drive (with view only permission). Only u can do the edit. all edit will be reflected on new downloads (@same link).

Comment: [which](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=create+costum+made+excel+template&ia=web) method did u used? any problem with the process? try to include/[edit] the troubleshooting info/sample template done/the error screenshot.. to help others to help.. ( :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for trying to help me and letting me know how general my question was, I will have to practice being more precise with my requests in the future.

I was lucky to find 'grouped worksheet' that managed to satisfy my needs. With grouped worksheet I am able to change the menu/character panel in all worksheets without changing other things. (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/group-worksheets-4e1f7747-3d63-4fd7-8a36-838b05adc0f0?fbclid=IwAR2fSw1diR6yFAz3DIBtEx9T-Bg6pm_oeuo6ncVlWRz3sr4fTJidteIPkUg)